# How to work with characters from CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B correctly?

Tags: front-end, bugs, unicode, character-encoding

**Background:**

Recently I'm trying to deal with some Chinese characters which belongs to the **CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B** block. The motive comes from some further interest following [a former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857289/getting-the-mathematica-front-end-to-obey-the-fontfamily-option), and some ideas of using Mathematica for typesetting ancient Chinese scriptures.

**Edit:**

Here is some sample code which looks fine at first sight ( The Unicodes of the three characters involved here are `x20027`, `x200D5` and `x20137`. The setting of the `$SystemCharacterEncoding` of my Mathematica is `"CP936"`. ):

[image]

But after saving then closing the notebook, I re-opened it, without touching anything, the Front End displays weird now (and note the attendance of the syntax errors):

[image]

It seems the Front End is not able to correctly render them.

Furthermore, although I can create a textcell looking fine:

[image]

whose `CellExpression` is:

```
Cell["\:d840\:dc27\:d840\:dcd5\:d840\:dd37", "Text", CellChangeTimes->{3.5359048507534103`*^9}]
```

but if I trig `Ctrl+Shift+E` and edit the `CellExpression` directly (eg. deleting the `CellChangeTimes` item, which should not affect the "appearance" of the cell), then convert the cell back to normal status, things get wrong again:

[image]

This kind of problem never happened when dealing with characters from **CJK Unified Ideographs** and **CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A** blocks, so I guess there may be a bug here.

So my questions is: While I do realize the `"Unicode"` encoding in Mathematica referring to only 16-bit Unicode while the CJK-B begin with `x20000`, is there any method to render and work with characters from **CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B** correctly?

Comment: I don't have time for this tonight, but I spent a lot of time with it before!  Please also see the comments on this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597013/reading-an-utf-8-encoded-text-file-in-mathematica).  You can also mail me, and I can perhaps send you some workaround code for handling them in the kernel, but I gave up on showing them in the front end.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks a lot! I always wonder maybe at the very start Mathematica is not designed for dealing with full Unicode range. I'll check the link you provided and maybe mail you later. It's 6:00 in the morning in China and I have to sleep awhile now.

Comment: Mathematica simply has no support for non-plane-0 characters. That it appears to temporarily work should not fool you into thinking that M-- knows anything about such values. Those who saw the R&D keynote at the 2011 Tech Conference may remember my relating the story of the pain we have experienced from the fact that we were extremely early adopters of Unicode, well before it was baked into OSes and the concept of Unicode planes had been fully developed.  It affects every part of the system, and will be difficult and expensive to fix when we finally do fix it.

Comment: @JohnFultz There would be value in adding support to the kernel only first (without display support by the front end).  By "support" I mean that string operations such as ToCharacter, FromCharacterCode, etc. should work correctly.

Comment: @JohnFultz I noticed [in 10.0 we can use the used-to-be-buggy characters now](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65958/17). May I consider it's a full support for all unicode characters?

Comment: @Silvia No, you should definitely not consider it full support.  My earlier statement stands unchanged for v10.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks for the clarification! At least things are getting better. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reposting John Fultz’s comment above as a “community wiki” answer for everyone to improve:

> Mathematica simply has no support for non-plane-0 characters. That it
>   appears to temporarily work should not fool you into thinking that M--
>   knows anything about such values. Those who saw the R&D keynote at the
>   2011 Tech Conference may remember my relating the story of the pain we
>   have experienced from the fact that we were extremely early adopters
>   of Unicode, well before it was baked into OSes and the concept of
>   Unicode planes had been fully developed. It affects every part of the
>   system, and will be difficult and expensive to fix when we finally do
>   fix it.