# Unicode beyond Basic Multilingual Plane

Tags: string-manipulation, text

String manipulation takes a dive when characters beyond `\:FFFF` are used e.g. [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols). The characters display fine but doing string manipulation is very unpredictable:

```
ToCharacterCode[""] (* Actually is \U0001d56c *)
StringLength[""]
(* {55349, 56684} *)
(* 2 *)
```

Compare with python

```
>>> len(u'') 
1
```

`$CharacterEncoding = "Unicode"` or `$CharacterEncoding = "UTF8"` does not help, is there some way to set string encoding properly?

Comment: Related SO questions: [How to enter non-BMP unicode hexadecimal with more than 4 characters as input to Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8059153/211232), [Reading an UTF-8 encoded text file in Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5597013/211232)

Comment: @WReach Thanks! Couldn't find them searching google and here.

Comment: @WReach Would you be willing to write a summary answer here, unless a duplicate already exists on *this* site?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I added a CW response that points to some of the related questions.  The present question is more general than [(215)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215/142), so I am unsure as to whether it should be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

As of version 10.1, *Mathematica* does not support characters beyond the basic multilingual pane.  John Fultz of WRI stated this explicitly as a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-to-work-with-characters-from-cjk-unified-ideographs-extension-b-correctly/3664#comment2344_215) on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215/142), which asks how to access supplementary CJK ideographs outside of Plane 0.

Some of the issues, and partial workarounds, are discussed on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8059153/211232) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5597013/211232).