# Can I read Chinese characters with ReadList correctly?

Tags: import, character-encoding, unicode

Just try this example:

```
Export["a.txt", "这乱码问题该怎么解决呢\n***\n怎么解决嘛"]
ReadList["a.txt", Record]
```

> ```
> {"è¿ä¹\[PlusMinus]ç é®é¢è¯¥æä¹è§£å\.b3å¢", "***", "æä¹è§£å\.b3å"}
> ```

I know `Import` can handle it correctly:

```
StringSplit@Import["a.txt"]
```

> ```
> {"这乱码问题该怎么解决呢", "***", "怎么解决嘛"}
> ```

But `ReadList` is generally much faster, right?

Well, after scanning [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215/1871) and the links inside it I noticed that *Mathematica* may be just not good at this, but still want to make sure if it's not possible.

Comment: "But ReadList is generally much faster, right?" Maybe not having to consider language encodings is one the reasons it is faster.

Comment: Have a look at `Trace[Import["a.txt"]]`

Comment: `ReadList` does not currently support character encodings.  You can use it to read the data as a sequence of pure bytes and then convert (using `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode`), but you can't get it directly from `ReadList`.

Comment: It's not just Chinese, it's anything non-Latin-1.  Try `Paul Erdős` and the ő will get mangled.

Comment: "much faster?" As I tested it, I can see `ReadList` is only a little faster than `Import`. When will `ReadList` be much faster than `Import`?

Comment: @matheorem As said above, `ReadList` is **generally** much faster, the timing in the answer below is an example, and you can find more by searching in this site. What sample did you use?

Comment: @xzczd I mean exporting and importing something like  `RandomReal[1.,{100000,3}]`

Comment: @matheorem How did you export the list? This is my timing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQek.png

Comment: @xzczd Oh, I really missed something! I use the `ReadList` in the wrong way. Thank you so much for showing this, it is really much faster : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most straightforward method is to read the data as a byte content, then interpret that as an UTF8 text. This is what it would look like:

```
FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList["a.txt"], "UTF8"]
```

It will be slightly more performant than the other suggestions as it avoids any unnecessary conversions. Be aware that you need to break into lines via e.g. `StringSplit` if so desired...

Answer (score 10):

Following the comments above, I think I've managed to find the answer, that is, as [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) and [librik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1638/librik) said, `ReadList` doesn't support character encoding, and maybe that's one of the reasons it's fast.

However, that doesn't mean we can't make use of `ReadList`. In fact, following the advice from [mfvonh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5059/mfvonh), I found that `Import` internally  uses `ReadList` to read `a.txt` first and then converts it to the right encoding with `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode` after a lot of judgments that I don't understand very well and seem to be redundant. So why not omit those judgments?:

```
Export["a.txt", "这乱码问题该怎么解决呢\n***\n1234\n这样解决呀"];
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[ReadList["a.txt", Record](*,"ISOLatin1"*)], 
                  "UTF8"] // AbsoluteTiming
Import["a.txt"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0010000, {"这乱码问题该怎么解决呢", "***", "1234", "这样解决呀"}}
> {0.0440000, Null}
> ```

Not sure if this will fail in more complicated cases.

Comment: 为这么萌的example点个赞