# Non-ASCII characters in txt file can't be import correctly by Mathematica10

Tags: import, character-encoding

I'm using Mathematica v10.0.2 on Win7.

I have a text file in which there are some Chinese characters and I would Import the file into Mathematica as a string by:

```
str=Import["...file.txt"]
```

However, the Chinese characters were all "translated" to strange characters like "Ò»Êø¹â".

Note that a string containing Chinese characters can be correctly `Export` ed to a txt file.

nothing changes when I try `$CharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"` or `$SystemCharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"`

what should I do?

Or is there any I can turn the "Ò»Êø¹â" back to the characters in original txt file?

Comment: maybe you can use option CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refering to [Can I read Chinese characters with ReadList correctly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48570/can-i-read-chinese-characters-with-readlist-correctly) here is the solution:

first try

```
FromCharacterCode[
ToCharacterCode[
ReadList["...file.txt", Record, 1]], #] & /@ $CharacterEncodings
```

read the output then select the one of $CharacterEncodings which correctly translated the characters (which may depend on your systems or Mathematica versions), inset it into the # in the code above.

for my Mma10.0.2 on Win7, It's "CP936" that works

```
FromCharacterCode[
ToCharacterCode[
ReadList["...file.txt", Record, 1]], "CP936"] & /@ $CharacterEncodings
```